# How to get properties from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm using this code to retrieve a simple JSON object:

```
function userinfo() {
    var user = new Object();
    $.getJSON('###', function(data){
        user.id = data.user.uID;
        user.name = data.user.uname;
    });
    return user;
}
var user = userinfo();
console.log(user);
```

When I run console.log on the user object outside of the function, I can see the properties of the object (id, name). But when I try to console.log "user.id" or "user.name", they come up as undefined. I can't work out why this is, or what I can do to retrieve the properties without having to iterate over them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue here is the OP doesnt understand what an asynchronous operation is.  Seems like a legitimate question for a learner.  The title could be phrased better to benefit posterity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AJAX call to get the JSON is asynchronous, the callback `function(data)` isn't called until the AJAX returns, but you are reading `user` right after the AJAX request is sent, but before the AJAX response is received.

Try this:

```
function userinfo() {    
    $.getJSON('###', function(data){
        var user = new Object();
        user.id = data.user.uID;
        user.name = data.user.uname;
        // Do your stuff here
        console.log(user);
    });
}

userinfo();
```

**Answer to comment:**
Just have a function like this on the app:

```
function processUser(user){
   console.log(user);
}
```

Then use it in the AJAX callback,

```
$.getJSON('###', function(data){
        var user = new Object();
        user.id = data.user.uID;
        user.name = data.user.uname;
        // Do your stuff here
        processUser(user);
    });
```

@Simon, you can do usual application logic in `processUser()` now, e.g.:

```
var usersList = []; // Assume this is a global for your app

function processUser(user){
   usersList.push(user);
   // now other parts of your app can find this user in the list
}
```

Comment: All I want to do is to get user.id and user.name out of that function and into the rest of the workspace. But, whenever I reference user, I need to make the getJSON call to make sure the values are accurate. How can I do that without surrounding the entire workspace in a getJSON call?

Comment: @SimonMunyard pass in a callback into your function which will set the value

Comment: @SimonMunyard there's no way around it. The response will not received untill you return. You need to wrap the depending code in a callback.

Comment: Ok, I can see what you're doing there. So let me ask this - can I put the output of processUser() into a variable that I can use anywhere?

Comment: @SimonMunyard whatever you do - you can't access the value before the callback has assigned it (which can happen arbitrarily late, no matter where the code is).

Comment: @JanDvorak Ok, so instead of telling me what I can't do, can you tell me what I can do? If it's impossible to do this then let me know so that I can work out another solution.

Comment: @SimonMunyard you need to wrap the dependent code in a callback. You can then pass the callback to the `get` (passing it as an argument to `userinfo` is one option)

Comment: Ok, so here's my new code:
`        var userList = [];
  function userinfo() {
   var user = new Object();
   $.getJSON('/login/user.html', function(data){
    //console.log(data.user);
    user.id = data.user.uID;
    user.name = data.user.uname;
    processUser(user);
   });
   
   //return user;
  }
  function processUser(user) {
   userList.push(user); 
  }
  
  console.log(userList);

This just shows an empty array.

Comment: @Simon, there's lots of ways, but the idea is that you cannot disregard the asynchronous aspect of your code if you are pulling data asynchronously. I agree it confuses in the beginning, after all the Python library for asynchronous networking wasn't called 'Twisted' for nothing ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks all. I think I will look for another way of dealing with the user info. I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function userinfo(callback) {
    $.getJSON('###', function(data){
        callback({
            id: data.user.uId,
            name: data.user.uname
        });
    });
}
var user;
userinfo(function(newUser) {
    user = newUser;
    // do work with user.
});

// execution continues here before callback returns.  User will not be set.

user.name // error no property name of undefined.
```

Comment: His original example showed needing the user object in the global scope (debateable).  This version provides a reusable function to perform the get.

Comment: I'm afraid this will confuse the asker into thinking he can use the value before he actually can.

Comment: Perhaps, it does follow the async pattern though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix:

```
function userinfo() {
    var user = new Object();
    $.ajax({
        async: false, //solution right here
        url: '/login/user.html',
        success: function (data) {
            user.id = data.user.uID;
            user.name = data.user.uname;
        }
    });
    return user;
}
var user = userinfo();
console.log(user.id);
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: In a real world app if you do this everywhere on all requests you'll get angry users. You won't notice now because you're probably doing local development with a very fast local network response. You don't want to block the app's execution flow just to wait for responses, at least not on every call!

Comment: Yeah, I understand. However, I am working on a remote server already, the resonding data size is very small, and the call isn't being made often - maybe once per session. I did use this method advisedly.